# How could I read a file with two columns in two arrays?

Tags: c

I wrote this function in C which import a two column file in two arrays and then finds the linear interpolation between two successive points if the input value of the function lies between them.

```
double Prevot_redden(double wave, double Av)
{
 int  i,j; 
 const double Rv = 2.75;  /* Set by Prevot */ 
 double       micron, r = 0.;
 micron = wave * 1e6;  /* convert to micron */
 /*Prevot reddening counters*/
 int raw_prevot_size=4002;
 /*data array for raw Prevot reddening */
 double *raw_prevot_wave_data,*raw_prevot_data;
 /*allocate space for raw Prevot reddening*/
 raw_prevot_wave_data=(double *)calloc(raw_prevot_size,sizeof(double *));
 raw_prevot_data=(double *)calloc(raw_prevot_size,sizeof(double *));
 /*reading a file*/
 char *f_prevot=fopen("SMC_prevot.dat","r");
 if (f_prevot==NULL ) 
 {
        fprintf(stderr,"Can not open reddening file !\n");
        exit(-1);
 }
 for (i=0;i<raw_prevot_size;i++)
 {
   sscanf(f_prevot,"%lf %lf",&raw_prevot_wave_data[i],&raw_prevot_data[i]);/*Wavelength and E(lambda-V)/E(B-V)*/
   /* convert to micron */
   raw_prevot_wave_data[i]*=1e-4;
 }

  for (j = 0; j < raw_prevot_size-2; j++)
  {
      if ((micron>raw_prevot_wave_data[j]) &&(micron<=raw_prevot_wave_data[j+1]))
      {

       r= lininterp(raw_prevot_wave_data[j],
                       raw_prevot_wave_data[j+1],
                       raw_prevot_data[j],
                       raw_prevot_data[j+1],
                       micron);
      }
  }
  r *= Av;
  r /= Rv;
  r /= -2.5;
  r  = pow(10, r);
  return(r);
}
```

When I compile the code, for the line with the command fopen, I get this warning message.
Can somebody explain what the reason is for the message?!!

```
In function 'Prevot_redden':
14: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need

```
FILE *f_prevot=fopen("SMC_prevot.dat","r");
·..

if (fscanf(f_prevot,"%lf %lf",&raw_prevot_wave_data[i],&raw_prevot_data[i]) == 2)
...
fclose(f_prevot);
```

Answer (score 0):

`FILE *f_prevot=fopen("SMC_prevot.dat","r");`

would be my first try as fopen returns a pointer of FILE * type

Comment: I am getting another warning if I change it to FILE             warning: passing argument 1 of 'sscanf' from incompatible pointer type
note: expected 'const char * __restrict__' but argument is of type 'struct FILE *'

Comment: sscanf will read from a C string, if you want to read from a file, better use fscnaf. See @CapelliC solution below.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *f_prevot=fopen("SMC_prevot.dat","r");
```

fopen() returns FILE*, not char*